# What is the maximum flux of 1 GeV stably-trapped protons in Jupiter radiation belts?

Tags: particle-physics, atmospheric-science, plasma-physics, solar-system, jupiter

And in which L-shell?

This graph shows a flux of around 50 stably-trapped protons per m2 per sec on Earth, and I have read it's higher in Jupiter but I can't find the value.
A source would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: One gives links when quoting, found this later plot https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.07112 , fig4

Answer (score 1):

From this review of the [radiation belts of Jupiter](https://www.cosmos.esa.int/documents/1866264/3219248/RoussosE_Roussos_Voyage2050_Jupiter_Radiation_Belts.pdf/d40b6389-612f-33f3-6e37-5dcc707811be?t=1565184658455),

> THE IN-SITU EXPLORATION OF
> JUPITER’S RADIATION BELTS

> A White Paper submitted in response
> to ESA’s Voyage 2050 Call:

...

> Jupiter’s radiation belts are contained within the planet’s magnetosphere, formed by a
> magnetic field that is 20,000 times stronger than Earth’s. Jupiter’s fast rotation and material
> from Io’s volcanoes that fills the system, aid the magnetic field to push against the solar wind
> even further, giving to the magnetosphere enormous dimensions . Within this
> giant system, the radiation belts grow into one of the most hazardous regions of our solar
> system, trapping charged particles of extreme energies and fluxes.

...

> Jupiter’s magnetic field is so strong that even ultrarelativistic, ~100 GeV protons can be
> trapped near the planet, over 50 times higher in energy than at Earth . Most importantly, observations and theory dictate that processes which
> may populate the radiation belts with ultrarelativistic particles do exist

...

> Jupiter’s belts have a distinctively large variety of ions in comparable abundance to protons.
> At other planets, ions at many MeV/n are typically
> trace elements. Heavy energetic ions at Jupiter, such as oxygen and sulphur, originate
> primarily from the moons through volcanism or particle sputtering. At lower abundances, ions
> like helium, sodium, magnesium, carbon etc., have been measured. Furthermore, some of the
> ions have a range of charge states
> et al. 2017].

There is an extensive list of references.

The paper is about future measurements and their complexity, at the moment, as far as I understand, the value of 100 GeV protons trapped  is expected from the models, the existing measurements do not go above 100 MeV due to the detecting systems on spacecraft in the region, JUNO.

...

From paragraph 2.2

> Jupiter’s innermost radiation belts (r<6 RJ), where very energetic
> protons from CRAND may get more easily trapped, are being sampled extensively only by
> Juno. Juno, however, cannot resolve the energies of protons above 100 MeV, even if the
> instrument noise they create is recorded .

So as far as Jupiter is concerned one has to maybe wait for the new ESA project for 2050 for real data on fluxes.

Answer (score 0):

The [Jovian magnetic field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetosphere_of_Jupiter) is very large and as such, allows for a rather extreme set of [radiation belts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Allen_radiation_belt).

The following are taken from [*Roussos et al.* [2021]](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10686-021-09801-0).  Note that it is a compilation of figures from [*Nénon* [2018]](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-01899128), [*Mauk* [2014]](https://doi.org/10.1002/2014JA020392), [*Mauk and Fox* [2010]](https://doi.org/10.1029/2010JA015660), [*Nénon et al.* [2017]](https://doi.org/10.1002/2017JA023893), and [*Nénon et al.* [2018]](https://doi.org/10.1029/2018JA025216).

[image: Jovian Radiation Belts]

> This graph shows a flux of around 50 stably-trapped protons per m2 per sec on Earth, and I have read it's higher in Jupiter but I can't find the value. A source would be appreciated.

The units shown in your figure are commonly called *number flux* in space [plasma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_(physics)) physics.  Note that for unit conversion 1 MeV<sup>-1</sup> = 10<sup>3</sup> GeV<sup>-1</sup> and 1 m<sup>-2</sup> = 10<sup>-4</sup> cm<sup>-2</sup>.  So multiply the magnitudes in my figure by 10<sup>-1</sup> for direct comparison with your figure from PAMELA and SAMPEX data (or just look at the black lines in the figures).

**Side Note:**  The *L* parameter refers to shells of constant magnetic field strength in an ideal dipole magnetic field.  Sometimes folks take care to tilt the dipole (relative to rotation axis and/or ecliptic plane) and add a stretched magnetotail.